# Duplicity restriction for component availability

Tags: magnolia

Within an area in Magnolia template, we could create 2 components.  We should restrict the user in a way that they don't create duplicate components.  Can we achieve this through configurations or this requires a custom property created?  Any pointers would be of great help!

areas:
  myArea:
    availableComponents:
      maxComponents: 2
      renderType: freemarker
      type: list
      Component1:
        id:
      Component2:
        id:

When we have created content with component1 then it shouldn't be available for selection later.

Answer (score 0):

You have already limited number of components to 2. What you can do extra is to [autogenerate each of the components](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Component+autogeneration) at area creation time and mark them as [not delete-able](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Component+definition#Componentdefinition-Componentproperties) so that editors can't remove them and can't add more of the same (due to `maxComponents` restriction either). This effectively limits everyone to use of max 1 component of given type, but also forces exactly 1 component of given type.
If you want anything more sophisticated, you need to code it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jan for your quick response.  It makes sense and I'll try it.  One more question.  If I have 3 available components and max components as 2.  Will I be able autogenerated all 3 components as non deletable?  Then it would voilate the max components rule right?

Comment: It would indeed violate the rule, but if I'm not mistaken, that rule is either applied only when manually adding items to the list, so autogeneration could violate it or it is applied when rendering the list, so you could technically add as many (over autogeneration or by other programatic means) and only first 2 would render anyway. You need to test it. Sorry.